# How do I resample to 5 min correctly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-resample

I am trying to resample 1 min bars to 5 min but I am getting incorrect results.

1 min data:

[image]

I am using this to resample:

```
df2.resample("5min").agg({'open':'first',
                          'high':'max',
                          'low:'min',
                          'close':'last'})
```

I get:

[image]

For the second row bar (00:00:00) the high should be 110.34 not 110.35, and the close shoulb be 110.33.

How do I fix this?

**EDIT 1 To create data:**

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.date_range("2021-09-23 23:55", periods=11, freq="1min")
df = pd.DataFrame(index = idx)
data = [110.34,
        110.33,110.34,110.33,110.33,110.33,
        110.32,110.35,110.34,110.32,110.33,
        ]
df['open'] = data
df['high'] = data
df['low'] = data
df['close'] = data

df2 = df.resample("5min").agg({'open':'first',
                          'high':'max',
                          'low':'min',
                          'close':'last'})
print(df)
print("----")
print(df2)
```

Comment: Your output is as expected. The data for the second row `00:00:00` represents 5 minute data *beginning* at `00:00:00`. i.e. from `00:00:00` to `00:04:00`

Comment: But I expect 00:00:00 to be 23:56:00 to 00:00:00. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why would you want 23:56:00 - 00:00:00? Are you trying to do rolling? Because the first should be 23:55:00 - 23:59:00, then the second 5 minute should be 00:00:00 - 00:04:00, and so on.

Comment: I wish the 5 minutes bars to be labelled by the final time. So 00:01:00 to 00:05:00 are labelled as 00:05:00

Comment: Is the issue the labelling or rather the results?

Comment: My labels are what I want, but the values are incorrect. e.g. The high of row 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can specify the `closed='right'` and `label='right'` optional keyword arguments

```
d = {'open':'first','high':'max',
        'low':'min','close':'last'}
df.resample("5min", closed='right', label='right').agg(d)
```

---

```
                       open    high     low   close
2021-09-23 23:55:00  110.34  110.34  110.34  110.34
2021-09-24 00:00:00  110.33  110.34  110.33  110.33
2021-09-24 00:05:00  110.32  110.35  110.32  110.33
```

Comment: This appears to work!  What would I get is I missed out the closed='right' argument and only had label='right'?

Comment: @ManInMoon If you don't specify `closed=right` then this would aggregate `2021-09-23 23:55:00` to `2021-09-23 23:59:00` and label it as `2021-09-24 00:00:00`

Comment: So closed='right' aggregates 23:56:00 to 24:00:00 and labels it as 00:00:00?

Comment: @ManInMoon That's correct!